# Scala collection class that can extend itself? AbstractSeq confusion

Tags: scala, inheritance, scala-collections

Inside the Scala standard library, I noticed this:

```
package scala
package collection
package mutable

import generic._
...

/** Explicit instantiation of the `Seq` trait to reduce class file size in subclasses. */
abstract class AbstractSeq[A] extends scala.collection.AbstractSeq[A] with Seq[A]
```

`AbstractSeq[A] extends AbstractSeq[A]  with Seq[A]?`

What is going on here?

Answer (score 5):

It is extending `scala.collection.AbstractSeq`, while the definition is of `scala.collection.mutable.AbstractSeq`, so those are different classes. (Note the different package names: `scala.collection` vs. `scala.collection.mutable`.)

Comment: Two questions. Is writing "package scala
package collection
package mutable" the same as "package scala.collection.mutable"? Second, what is this "reduce class file size" Seq thing?

Comment: I am just guessing for the second question, but usually `mutable.AbstractSeq` would also be a `generic.Seq` in most of the implementations, though in case those methods (implemented `Seq`) were not mixed in at this point, the trait implementations would have to be generated for the other implementation classes too, so in case you had 5 concrete classes, you would have 5 times the byte code for those, while in this case -because of virtual calls- just once (and still be able to override them).

Answer (score 3):

They are different classes. The one you are looking at is `scala.collection.mutable.AbstractSeq`, the one it is extending is `scala.collection.AbstractSeq`.

Package is a kind of namespace. Different classes can have the same name as long as they are in different packages.

Comment: Two questions. Is writing "package scala package collection package mutable" the same as "package scala.collection.mutable"? Second, what is this "instantiation... reduce class file size" Seq thing?

Comment: Yes, it is the same. I am not sure about the second question. Seems to have something to do with how scala internally generates classes, that inherit from multiple traits.